# Using JavaBDD in C#

Tags: c#, java, .net

Is there any tutorial for using JavaBDD in C#? I's days i'm looking for it with no chance :(
It's JavaBDD website: http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Unless you can find a .NET port, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know of none, unless there is, or you can create, an interface that is heterogenous (web service, for example, or wrapping with a COM wrapper?). A quick search shows other BDD libs out there. Have you considered seeing if any provides either a COM or native Win interface. Then you can either add a .NET wrapper (include a reference) or PInvoke the lib.